# Specializations that are structurally identical

Tags: c++, templates, specialization

Consider the two partial specializations below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename, typename...> struct A;

template <typename... Ts>
struct A<int, Ts...> {
    void foo (int a) const {std::cout << a << '\n';}
    void operator()(const std::vector<int>& v) const {std::cout << v.size() << '\n';}
};

template <typename... Ts>
struct A<char, Ts...> {
    void foo (char a) const {std::cout << a << '\n';}
    void operator()(const std::vector<char>& v) const {std::cout << v.size() << '\n';}
};

int main() {
    A<int, long, double> a;
    A<char, float, bool, short> b;
    a.foo(5);  // 5
    b.foo('!');  // !
    a({1,2,3});  // 3
    b({1,2,3});  // 3
}
```

How to write the two specializations just once?

```
template <typename T, typename... Ts>
struct A<T, Ts...> {
    static_assert (std::is_same<T,int>::value || std::is_same<T,char>::value, "Error");
    void foo (T a) const {std::cout << a << '\n';}
    void operator()(const std::vector<T>& v) const {std::cout << v.size() << '\n';}
};
```

doesn't work because it doesn't specialize anything, and I can't place `class = std::enable_if<std::is_same<T,int>::value || std::is_same<T,char>::value, T>::type` anywhere because a default argument cannot go after a pack.  The above specializations shall only be for int and char.  Any other type will some other general definition for the class.

Comment: Move the identical part into a separate template, then use inheritance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is better.

```
template <typename T> struct B
{
    void foo (T a) const
    {
        std::cout << a << '\n';
    }
    void operator()(const std::vector<T>& v) const
    {
        std::cout << v.size() << '\n';
    }

};

template <typename T, typename... Ts>
struct A {};

template <typename... Ts>
struct A<int,Ts...> :public B<int>
    {};
template <typename... Ts>
struct A<char,Ts...> :public B<char>
    {};


int main()
{
    A<int, long, double> a;
    A<char, float, bool, short> b;
    a.foo(5);  // 5
    b.foo('!');  // !
    a( {1,2,3}); // 3
    b( {1,2,3}); // 3
}
```

**This way is more simple and clean.**

Comment: But I want that form only for T = int and T = char.  Any other T shall give a different form for the struct.

Comment: Yeah, you are right.  But in my program code, my `A<T, Ts...>` class is actually derived from another template class that has `Ts...`, so my B<int, Ts...>` class actually needs `Ts...` because it is being placed between the two classes and uses `Ts...` in its operator().  But your solution gets my vote.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, to T.C., as always:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename, typename...> struct A;

template <typename T, typename... Ts>
struct B {
    void foo (T a) const {std::cout << a << '\n';}
    void operator()(const std::vector<T>& v) const {std::cout << v.size() << '\n';}
};

template <typename... Ts>
struct A<int, Ts...> : B<int, Ts...> {};

template <typename... Ts>
struct A<char, Ts...> : B<char, Ts...> {};


int main() {
    A<int, long, double> a;
    A<char, float, bool, short> b;
    a.foo(5);  // 5
    b.foo('!');  // !
    a({1,2,3});  // 3
    b({1,2,3});  // 3
}
```